# MAUI Http calls to local API freeze on android device, but not on windows

Tags: multithreading, httpclient, deadlock, maui, maui-windows

For some reason my http calls to local api freezes on await when running MAUI application on my android device, but works as intended when running it on windows.

The flow:

```
public ICommand LoginCommand => _loginCommand ??=
            new Command(async () =>
            {
                if (await _userService.Login(Username, Password))
                {
                    Navigate("//chatrooms");
                }
            });
```

```
public async Task<bool> Login(string username, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await _barigaProApiClient.SignIn(
                    new SignInRequest
                    {
                        Username = username,
                        Password = password
                    });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
            
            return true;
        }
```

```
public async Task<SignInResponse> SignIn(SignInRequest request)
        {
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await _client.PostAsync("/api/User/SignIn", content); // stuck here
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SignInResponse>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
```

At first I thought it could be a deadlock and unmanaged synchronization context.
Found an article with similar problem, got a suggestion to use .ConfigureAwait(false) to fix that, but it still did not work.

Comment: are you using `localhost` for your url?  90% of these problems are caused by that.

Comment: @Jason I ran it on my router ip. 192.168.0.x
I also made an inbound rule on firewall to allow port access to it, but it still didn't help.
Anyway I just realized that it is actually a problem on hosting the application, not the MAUI issue.
I used ngrok to make it accessible online, and it works now.

Comment: 9.9% of them are caused by a local webhost that does not allow remote connections